# PHP Mailer sends empty attachment

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I am trying to send an attached file from a contact form. I am basing my code using the phpMailer example yet in doing so no attachment is sent. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The name of the attached input is clientResume.

```
<div id='contactForm' class='animated'>
    <div id='formClose'>X</div>
    <form id="form" action="employerForm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <h1>Get Started For Free!</h1>
       <label>Name</label>
       <input class="formField" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="clientName" required>
       <label>Email</label>
       <input class="formField" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="clientEmail" required>
       <label>Resume</label>
       <input class="formField" placeholder="Resume" type="file" name="clientResume" required>
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">
       <input id='formButton' type='button' value='Submit'>
    </form>
</div>

var name = $('input[name="clientName"]').val(),
        email = $('input[name="clientEmail"]').val(),
        company = $('input[name="clientCompany"]').val(),
        comment = $('input[name="clientComment"]').val(),
        resume = $('input[name="clientResume"]').val(),
        form = $(document).find("form"),
        formData = form.serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    AccessControlAllowOrigin: '*';
});

<?php

        require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $name = $_POST['clientName'];
        $email = $_POST['clientEmail'];
        $attachment = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['clientResume']['tmp_name']));

        $subject = "Resume Submission [$name]";
        $message = "Name: $name " . "<br>Email: $email";

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = 'correlation-host.correlation-one.com';    
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->addAddress('mpaccione1991@gmail.com', 'Michael Paccione');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['clientResume']['name']));
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['clientResume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'resume');
        }
        $mail->msgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
        $mail->SmtpClose();


    ?>
```

Comment: what is this function return tempnam()?

Comment: It's from the php mailer upload example on github. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel yet again; base your code on [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

You're not doing a `move_uploaded_file`, so your upload is not safe. You copied the part about making a safe file name, but not the move following it, so your `addAttachment` call points at nothing. Do it like this:

```
$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['clientResume']['name']));
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['clientResume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
    ...
```

Your form is missing a hidden `MAX_FILE_SIZE` element before your file input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">
```

All this is also covered in [the PHP docs on handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). It's always a good idea to search and read the source docs before posting on SO.

Comment: This doesn't work either. No file gets attached this way.

Comment: It looks like the error may be in the the ajax request as it seems there are special requirements for sending files with AJAX I will check back when I have looked deeper into it.

Comment: Dump the contents of $_POST into a log file  and/or use web inspector so you can be sure what your request is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

$mail->addAttachment($attachment);

Where $attachment is something like $attachment = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['clientResume']['tmp_name'], $target);

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand, what would $target be?

Comment: $target is the path to the folder where you want to store the file.  eg. $target = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['clientResume']['name'];

Comment: Oh I dont want to store the file... I just want to take it from the contact form on the website and then email it right away. No server storage preferrably.

Comment: Yes, add  enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag

Comment: Ah I was missing that. I've updated the post to reflect that part. Adding the enctype still no good on the attachment.

Comment: $tempname = $_FILES['clientResume']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['clientResume']['name'];
$mail->addAttachment($tempname, $filename);

Comment: You have to store the file temporarily, not least because PHP already does that; you can always delete after you've sent it.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to acces the FormData js API to properly send the attachment from the front end.

```
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("clientName", name);
            fd.append("clientEmail", email);
            fd.append("clientResume", $(document).find('input[name="clientResume"]')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.attr('action'),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: fd,
                datatype: 'json'
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this type to attach the file

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['clientResume']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['clientResume']['name']);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In fact whereas before it was at least attaching an empty attachment... now there is no attachment sent.

Comment: $mail->Body =$message ; try this one to send instead of $mail->msgHTML($message);

Comment: Still no attachment =/

Comment: Don't do that, it's not safe.